# awk fast column retrieval from a large file

Tags: awk

If you have a file with 500K columns and you need to pull out each column one by one, as you progress from $1 to $500K, it takes longer and longer. Is there a fast way of doing this besides just doing a simple `{print $column_index}`? Columns at the same index are being pulled out from two files and juxtaposed and put in a separate file. So, `awk`'s job is to pull out a column from file-1 and file-2 and I could use `paste` to juxtapose the two columns. The example below is only for one file.

Test data:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1 20000); do perl -e 'print "0.001\t"x500000 . "\n"'; done > file-big-1.txt
```

Timing:

```
time awk '{print $1000}' file-big-1.txt > /dev/null

real 5m18.143s 
user 1m19.506s 
sys  0m57.417s

time awk '{print $450000}' file-big-1.txt > /dev/null

real    12m52.124s
user    9m22.182s
sys     0m52.987s
```

I have a working solution for this, where I `cut` the two files into 5K columns subsets and work on the subsets, and it is reasonably fast. 
Another solution which I haven't implemented yet is to transpose the files and work on rows. However, transposing such a large file is probably pretty tricky if the code requires to have all of the data loaded into memory first.
This is just a curiosity as I can work on split chunks. I just thought surely there is a better way.

Add on question to this, is there a way to transpose the file without sticking the data into an array first?

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now it doesn't make sense. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Did my best! :)

Comment: Having so many columns is slow by nature. `awk` has to split this monster record into fields and store them in heap memory. Many `awk` implementations come even with a limit on the number of columns. `gawk` doesn't, but sure it will get slow.

Comment: When you say store them in heap memory, I assume it doesn't store anything except the values for the required column? And storing one row probably doesn't take up that much memory. I thought it was slow because it needs to find and count the delimiters?! Also, in terms of memory it shouldn't make any difference whether its column 1 or column 500000, right?

Comment: Both is true, as I said. It needs to a) split the record into fields (which includes searching for the delimiter) and b) store fields into memory (which has to be allocated btw)

Comment: Anyhow, I admit that it is surprising that `{print $1}` takes longer than `{print $450000}`

Comment: $1 - real 5m18.143s;      $450000 - real   12m52.124s

Comment: just curious what could be a use case for such a file format?  Also, did you try `cut`, might work faster.  Another idea is do multiple columns at once (to different files) so you scan the file only once.   Incremental cost should be minimal.

Comment: @karakfa `cut`'s time seems to be invariant to column index, it takes around 5 minutes for any column. But for the first 5,000 `gawk`'s time is also around 5 mins, and since I am processing the data in 5,000-column chunks, it doesn't make a difference, but as I said above I do use `cut` to chop the file into 5,000-column chunks. Regarding use case, it's data related to DNA/genotype calling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how wide your columns are on average, but the following `sed` command can easily transform 5000 or so 100-character wide, space separated, columns into separate lines in about 20 milliseconds:

```
sed 's/ /\
/g'
```

If your data has multiple lines of so many columns then I would recommend also substituting some other unique record separator character (e.g. ASCII RS) for each newline in the input.

You could also write a very simple little column-to-line splitter in any language that can do buffered I/O (e.g. C) if you're worried about trying to read a whole very wide line into memory at a time; though if I were doing that on any type of system with decent virtual memory support, and with an address space larger than the file size, then I'd be tempted to `mmap()` the the whole file so that it can be treated as an array, then scan it and replace each column separator with a newline in one pass; thus avoiding all the `read()`/`write()` buffering and regular expression parsing nonsense.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Your code will just output everything into one column?!

Comment: I'm showing you how to transpose a line of 5000 columns into a set of 5000 lines, with almost zero effort and time.  You can now read and process the data line at a time instead of column at a time, and any `awk` can do that orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I had played around with the same idea with `gawk`'s `gsub`, which probably is just as fast.

Comment: Indeed `gsub()` could do much the same, though then effectively needing two `awk` processes, and it generally has a bit more overhead than `sed`, though perhaps negligible in this case.  The right tool for the job, and all that...